# How to reference a macro in a module if the module name changed VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reference macros that are in module that i have changed their name because the list was growing and i needed to have a specific name so i don't start searching to find the right one. My problem is that i am creating a custom ribbon menu and i am trying to assign the macros to buttons but i can only successfully reference the macros that are in standard named modules ex `module1`. The image below will clarify my situation.

[image: Module Name]

Below is my code to create the buttons i'm still experimenting with it to see but what i am trying to achieve is square buttons is someone can point me in the right direction that will be amazing. At the moment the only button that works is the upperCase and RemoveAddIn that it lives in `Module1`.

```
Private Sub AddButtons()
     '
     'change 'Startups...' to suit
    Const MyControl As String = "Applications..."
     'change 'Manage Startups' to suit
    Const MyControlCaption As String = "Manage Applications"
     '
    Dim AddinTitle As String, Mybar As Object
     '
    AddinTitle = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)
     '
    Call RemoveButtons
     '
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set Mybar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar") _
    .Controls("Tools").Controls _
    .Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=13)
     '
    With Mybar
        .BeginGroup = True
        .Caption = MyControl
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
        .Controls.Add.Caption = MyControlCaption
        .Controls(MyControlCaption).OnAction = "ShowStartupForm"
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
        With .Controls.Add
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "About " & AddinTitle
        End With
        .Controls("About " & AddinTitle).OnAction = "ShowAboutForm"
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
        .Controls.Add.Caption = "Remove " & AddinTitle
        .Controls("Remove " & AddinTitle).OnAction = "RemoveAddIn"
        .Controls.Add.Caption = "upperCase " & AddinTitle
        .Controls("upperCase " & AddinTitle).OnAction = "upperCase"
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
    End With
    Exit Sub
     '
ErrHandler:
    Set Mybar = Nothing
    Set Mybar = Application.CommandBars("Tools") _
    .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=13)
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You could try adding the module name e.g. 'OnAction = "Filter.ShowAboutForm"'

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks a lot yes it works fine didn't know that you needed to put the rename module and then the actual procedure name because if it's not rename then it works without putting `Module1.lowerCase` and actually works fine with just `"lowerCase"` don't know why.

Comment: The module name is probably defaulting to the module in which the calling code is found - so, if the line `.Controls("About " & AddinTitle).OnAction = "ShowAboutForm"` is located in `Module1` then it will default to `.Controls("About " & AddinTitle).OnAction = "Module1.ShowAboutForm"`